# Netbeans 6.8 the breakpoint icon isn't a pink square but a vertically cutted in half pink square

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8, breakpoints

I'm using Netbeans 6.8. When I add a break point an icon is added next to the line of code. This the icon is not a pink square, but a vertically cut in half pink square.

Is this the new icon that symbolizes the break point? I expected a non-broken pink square

Answer (score 3):

this icon symbolizes that the break point has been set at an invalid location.

Comment: Thanks! so not all code lines in a program are valid to add a breakpoint ?!?!?? In what cases could be invalid ??

Comment: Well, putting a breakpoint on a comment wouldn't be valid.  Nor, on certain non-executable declarations.

Comment: secondary lines of a multiple line statement also tend to get marked as invalid.